# HttpsURLConnection show Security Warning Dialog rather than catch Exception

Tags: java, exception, https, java-web-start, httpsurlconnection

I make an `HttpsURLConnection` as below:

```
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL( host );
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            logger.debug( httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            logger.error( ex.getMessage() );
        }
```

The `host` I tested doesn't have a valid certificate, so when I tested within Eclipse, it catch `SSLHandshakeException` which its fine.

However, when I deployed as WebStart, it doesn't go to catch clause but showing me the warning dialog instead:

[image]

If user click Continue, it passes the `connect()` successfully.

Is there anyway that I can catch the exception instead allowing User to click Continue from this dialog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the dialog use this:

`connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);`

Now you should get the exception immediately if the JVM is not happy with the certificate.

Comment: it looks like a valid setting, thanks! unfortunately, i will try it out another time since I already found a workaround by not calling "connect" but making an API request (like ping) instead and it catches exception successfully if failure

Answer (score 2):

Java WebStart plugs its own SSLSocketFactory

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/security.html

> Dynamic Downloading of HTTPS Certificates
>
> Java Web Start dynamically imports certificates as browsers typically
>   do. To do this, Java Web Start sets its own https handler, using the
>   java.protocol.handler.pkgs system properties, to initialize defaults
>   for the SSLSocketFactory and HostnameVerifier. It sets the defaults
>   with the methods HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory and
>   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier.
>
> If your application uses these two methods, ensure that they are
>   invoked after the Java Web Start initializes the https handler,
>   otherwise your custom handler will be replaced by the Java Web Start
>   default handler.
>
> You can ensure that your own customized SSLSocketFactory and
>   HostnameVerifiter are used by doing one of the following:
>
> Install your own https handler, to replace the Java Web Start https
>   handler. In your application, invoke
>   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory or
>   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier only after the first
>   https URL object is created, which executes the Java Web Start https
>   handler initialization code first.

You may be able to revert in your code with

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

I did not check the mileage how to get the original SSLContext, you may need to dig deeper.

Comment: thanks, very helpful information, now i know why it doesnt work as expected with Webstart. However, i havent tried it out since i found another workaround. Will dig deeper this approach.